# Publish an add-on from Standalone Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have developed a google sheet addon, I had succefully published that add-on from Google sheet bound script ie from **tools->Script editor.**

But If I made direct google apps script project(standalone project),I am unable to publish it,**And a notification is popped up.**

[image]

I research that I need it to setup it from google console,to publish standalone google app script to add-on ,But I don't found exact options to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction is a very confusing for a first timer. Google keeps redirecting you to the page describing publishing editor addons, but what you really need is the page describing how to create a project on cloud platform.

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project

Steps:

1. Create Project and get Project Number using instructions from link above
2. Go to you script. Select in the menu Resources > Cloud Platform projects... and enter your project number there
3. Then google will ask you to setup OAuth
4. After that, you can move your script to cloud platform and publish.

Answer (score 1):

To publish an addon for G Suite Document editors follow the instructions here

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons

The specific part about the GCP project is

> Technical
>
> - The add-on script project must use a [standard Cloud Platform (GCP) project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects). If the script project currently uses a default GCP project, you must [switch to a standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switch_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project). All collaborators working on the add-on should have access to the standard GCP project.