# Conflicting Answers For Publishing Google Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have developed a Google add-ons standalone script (for Google Docs) and tried to publish it via Google Workspace Marketplace SDK whilst getting verification for OAuth consent screen at the same.

However, Google Cloud Trust & Safety team (for OAuth consent screen) rejected the verification application as they mentioned **the app must be published first before obtaining OAuth verification**. On the other hand, GWM Reviews Team said that **the app cannot be published without verification from OAuth**.

This is pretty confusing and conflicting on one another.
Has anyone encountered this before? Some guidance and advise on this matter is very much appreciated.

Additional Info:

- The app is set to publish on **Public** and **Unlisted**
- I have tried to develop the Google docs add-on via a container-script bound before transferring it to a standalone script for general Google Doc usage.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57028715/7215091

Comment: @Cooper I have followed through as mentioned for that answer:
Link Apps Script with Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project (under Standard). Then under the OAuth consent screen, set **Publishing Status** to be **in Production** in order to initialize verification process. However, the Google Cloud Trust & Safety team told me as what I have stated above. So I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it approved and here's what I did:

- I started a new project and copied & pasted the existing codes onto new app scripts
- Followed the procedure from this link:
  https://medium.com/@efrem.sternbach/how-i-published-a-google-sheets-add-on-or-wtf-google-483a66833d70/
- I think the most crucial point is when you select the app type on **Google Workspace Marketplace SDK**, under App Integration.

  - Previously I have selected *Google Workspace Add-on*, but the new project was under **Docs Add-on**.
  - The rest of the stuffs (from credential, project settings, etc) are practical the same
- After rounds of amendments as requested by the teams, it was finally approved

**Tips: Always switch between legacy and new app script editor. Some of the legacy's features are still in use which proves to be helpful**